# Движение текста

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блок:

```
<header>
  <div class="data-text">
     <span>Текст для примера</span>
  </div>
</header>
```

Как сделать, чтобы, когда мышь попадает на блок `data-text`, текст начинал двигаться как здесь https://exmo.com/ по линии?

Comment: так там не текст двигается )

Comment: а мне текст нужен)

Comment: вот  я и в ступаре как это организовать

Comment: Попробуйте поиграться с [библиотечкой этой](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/).

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду изменение курсора? Или вам интересно воспроизвести такой интерактивный фон? Вопрос не ясен..., уточните.

Comment: взависимости от положения курсора по блоку, нужно чтобы блок текста так двигался как на примере

Comment: там только вроде с картинкой

Comment: @Aslero, смысл похожий

Comment: я что-то не разобрался как там блок использовать